# RPM Generation X86_64

Tags: rpm

I am generating RPM for the fisrt time. I have created folder structure

mkdir -p tmp/rpm/{BUILD,BUILDROOT,RPMS/x86_64,SOURCES,SRPMS,SPECS} .

But when I generated my RPM, it generates my RPM with i586 extension. How to tell RPM to generate x86_64 extension

Answer (score 1):

`rpmbuild` doesn't do major-arch crosscompiling. Build your package on a x86-64 system, with x86-64 tools.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to use http://build.opensuse.org as it builds for both i386 and x86_64 as well as taking care of both RedHat, SuSE, CentOS and Debian.

The other thing to do if you don't want to use build.opensuse.org is to set the arch environment variable. The first option though is the easier.